# pear mail not working

Tags: php, email, pear

My use of Pear to relay one of our site's users ('sender') email to another user ('recipient') fails because the recipient user always receives the mail in their spam folder.  For the explanation below, our website is called "oursite.com."

I have narrowed this down after 2 solid days of lots of experimenting to the "From" part of the 'headers' as follows  (for the sake of this example, my name is *Sam Hambone* and I have no idea how the 'From:' in the title of the email is grabbing my name and using it as described below):

```
      $senderEmail = "IamTheSender@gmail.com";

      // this version of the 'from' variable makes the 'From' in the email's title
      // look correct, like this: "IamTheSender@gmail.com (IamTheSender@gmail.com)"
      // but when the recipient gets the mail, it will ALWAYS go into the 'junk'
      // or 'spam' email folder of the recipient's inbox.  NOTE: using angle brackets
      // instead of parentheses here changes nothing.
      $from = $senderEmail . " (" . $senderEmail . ")";

      // this second version of 'from' makes the mail arrive correctly
      // in the recipient's Inbox and not in their spam/junk folder, but
      // the "From:" line in the email's title looks like this:
      // "Sam Hambone (IamTheSender@gmail.com)"
      $from = $senderEmail;
```

EDIT:  here is what the email's title and headers look like using the 1st version of 'from' above -- in this case I sent an email to myself as the recipient:

```
 'Sender has a question for you, Mr. Recipient!'
 Sam Hambone (IamTheSender@gmail.com) << this is wrong -- it's mixing my (recipient)
                                         real name with the sender's email address!!
 To: sammyhambone@hotmail.com
 From:  IamTheSender@gmail.com
 Sent:  Fri 10/18/13 5:49 PM
 To:    sammyhambone@hotmail.com (sammyhambone@hotmail.com)
```

Here is the rest of the code -- this code successfully sends out the email, but by using one of the above versions of the **from** variable, I either find the email go to the recipient's Junk folder or the 'From:' part in the email's title is screwed up as described above:

```
  $theRecipient = "aLoyalUser@hotmail.com";
  $to = $theRecipient . " (" . $theRecipient . ")";   
  $subject = "the subject is Pear and emailing.";
  $body = "Ach, megotts lads, comes the blarney stone."

  $host = "smtp.1and1.com";   
  $port = "25";      
  $username = "myAuthName@oursite.com";  
  $password = "12345";   

  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
               array ('host' => $host,
                 'port' => $port,
                 'auth' => true,
                 'username' => $username,
                 'password' => $password));

 $headers['From'] = $from; // one of the two 'from' versions given above 
 $headers['To'] = $to;
 $headers['Subject'] = $subject;            

 $mail = $smtp->send($theRecipient, $headers, $body);

    // tried this, no help
 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```

I need to get the Sender's email message to the Recipient's Inbox but the "From:" part of the email's title must not say "Sam Hambone (IamTheSender@gmail.com)".

What's missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best example of a website that probably everyone is familiar with is -- I have noticed that sites like Craigslist are always able to get emails routed to me when I place an ad to sell something (clothes, furniture, etc.)

There are other examples where a website 'relays' one of their user's email to my inbox successfully.  That is what I was after, as that is what our site needs to do -- when a user needs to contact another user they send an email through our site (since that's how they came to be aware of the other user) and we need to relay their email to our other user.

No one (yet?) seems to have concrete experience on how to do this, so I'll close out this question in just a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As you may or may not know, there is a war on spam *.  This is because spammers are so prolific that they're using a significant amount of resources on servers like processing power (for filtering spam).  They also threaten to ruin the usefulness of things like e-mail if we do not stop them.  Therefore, because they're a major practical concern, there are all sorts of very sensitive spam filters across the internet that will put you in junk mail for reasons ranging like sending to too many messages that bounce, sending to a particularly unlucky inactive e-mail address (called a spam trap), etc.  It is conceivable that the anti-spam software that is running is using this particular e-mail from format as one of it's heuristics to detect spam.  It might be argued that using this as a heuristic is irrational or overly-sensitive, but as I've mentioned, the war on spam has resulted in some spam filtering mechanisms that are quite sensitive.  If you want to do a test, perhaps try white listing the from e-mail address or turning off the spam filter(s) (in addition to server-side filters, e-mail clients and virus scanners may include some filtering abilities) and see if the spam filter is the culprit.

Update: Now that I am aware of the purpose of this e-mail software (to relay a message sent from the site from one user to another user, while presumably protecting their privacy) I can provide a better suggestion:

The notifications that I receive from websites to tell me that a user has messaged me simply contain the name of the website in the from line rather than a person's name.  Example:

Website Name (no-reply@websitename.com)

(Note - it could be important to some spam filters that the website name in the from line matches the domain name exactly.)

If that doesn't seem to make it through the spam filter, I would try the following ideas:

1. Check out other "from" lines from other websites to see how they're doing it and try out any patterns you find.
2. Consider signing up with an e-mail reputation service to see whether they can help you.
3. Test to see whether this quirk is a big issue or a small one by determining which specific piece of spam software is flagging these, and then finding out how many users they have.  You could also try sending these e-mails to a variety of other e-mail services to see whether they junk them.  It may be that you have some old or unpopular spam filter here that's behaving in a way which actually is not indicative of what will happen to most of your e-mails.

   - Citation: "Spam Wars" by MIT Technology Review

Comment: Our team's seeking to avoid having to tell our users "be sure to check your 'junk' email folder because all the emails we send get treated as spam."  I know there's gotta be a way other than that, asking all our users to whitelist incoming emails, because the web sites I interact with on a daily basis are able to get an email through clean, no problem, without having to be whitelisted.  I have not had a website that is 'new to me' tell me "we're sending you a confirmation email, but check your spam folder" -- I haven't see that kind of message in YEARS.  Gotta be a way.

Comment: While I would not suggest simply allowing the e-mails to go into a spam folder, I would suggest experimenting to see whether other variations can get through.  Now that I know what type of e-mail the site is sending (relaying messages for a user in a way that presumably protects their identity) I have a new suggestion which I will update my answer with.

Comment: I spent a few hours this weekend modifying our site to display a lightbox that tells the user "be sure to check your email spam or junk folder because we can't guarantee the emails this site sends you will make it past your spam filter."  I really hate to do that.  I feel like I'm creating work-arounds solely due to the actions of spammers.  All our site does is make 'connections' between party A and party B.  And yet I will end up having to either drop the email relay and just host the messages on our site and tell users 'check for messages now and then' or use the above lightbox.